# OpenCV detect image border

Tags: image, opencv, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2

I have a set of damaged images - the have been splitted into two pieces via vertical line and their order was changed. Now I need to fix them on Raspberry Pi using OpenCV. How to  fix them? And to fix them fast?

[image: example of damaged picture]

Comment: Curious: how'd they get like that?

Comment: Probably broken camera driver in RaspberryPi. There's a robotic competition comming and fixing of the image is a last deperate try to make it work

Comment: I'd try fix that instead of doing it "in post" :)

Comment: That's what I have been doing for last two days...

Comment: Is this Shift always constant or varying?

Comment: Varying. Outherwise it would be trivial. I tried to use Canny and then HoughLines (taking only vertical lines). It works quite well, however HoughLines doesn't compute length of the line - there are pictures, where a line inside the picture is also outlined and I have no clue, which line is the right one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to solve this problem - after a lots of research I found out there is a bug in the camera driver on RasPi - it is trating power management bad. There's a problem in synchronisation of the wake-up and capture of the frame, so every first frame after waku-up is corrupted. The solution is simple - throw away first frame and then immediately capture second - not corrupted - frame.

Answer (score 0):

- If the split is in the same place every time, a photoshop action/macro could do this.
- Try use canny edge detection to see a dramatic difference in pixels and then filter the edges by vertical lines